# What are my options for hanging a curtain in an archway?

Tags: curtain-rail, rental

One of the walls of my cinema room has a rectangular cut-out that's 1.8m long  and 2.1m high (approximately 6′×7′). I have a blackout curtain with eyelets that I'd like to hang in this archway so that I can watch TV in the dark. The wall is 110mm (≈4″) thick rendered single-brick. I would prefer an installation within the archway rather than on the wall.

I was initially thinking that I'd use an expanding tension-rod but my mum (who's hemming the curtain) doesn't think that it would support the weight of the curtain. I've also seen adjustable pillar ends which can fit a rod that has been cut to size.

I'm renting so I would prefer something temporary but I can contact the landlord for permission if the best option involves some drilling. What are my options?

Comment: If it is an archway (a picture would have been nice) and you have a straight curtain rod, you'll get light in from above the rod.  Maybe a folding privacy screen would suffice.

Comment: @SteveWellens I don't know if archway is quite the right word. It's a rectangular cut-out so the top edge is flat. There will be a slight gap "seam" between the top of the curtain so it's not rubbing but it shouldn't allow too much light ingress. Light won't be cast onto the screen anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the tension rod does not curve or buckle, then you just have to worry about the ends sliding down.  So, for each side, place a 1x4 or similar piece of wood against the jamb face. The wood should extend from the floor to just above the tension rod. Then, at rod height, a small piece of wood or metal can be attached to the upright piece. The tension rod pushes outward against your new uprights and rests on the small cross pieces. You can paint or finish the uprights to blend with the wall.